# Asus N751JK, Ubuntu 14,04, can't detect Nvidia geforce gtx 850m, can't install drivers

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm trying to get ubuntu to detect my nvidia card, but nothing seems to work.
I tried following a number of solutions, uninstalling nouveau, installing propriety drivers, downloading nvidia settings, and so on.
Additional Drivers says there are no drivers available, and Driver Manager comes up blank.

lspci | grep VGA gives back this

```
$ lspci | grep VGA 00:02.0 VGA compatible
controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated
Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'

```
sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
```

I'm relatively new at this, and am a little confused as to what I should be doing. Any help would be very much appreciated. :)

Output lspci -k | grep -E 'VGA|3D' -A2

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 17bd
Kernel driver in use: i915
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 17bd
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -E 'VGA|3D' -A2`

Comment: It looks like the driver is already installed OK. What is the problem?

Comment: I cannot choose to use the nvidia card. Maybe I've missed something, but my husband installed nvidia settings last night, and it wouldn't allow us to select the nvidia card.

Comment: Ok, something has changed. Desktop Effects are now working, and nvidia settings allows me to select the nvidia card.
You are a star! Thank you ever so much! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you tried to download, install or configure. It can make things more complicated. I suggest installing the system from scratch to avoid possible problems.

The main issue is that default Nvidia proprietary driver in Ubuntu repositories does not support this new adapter.

In a freshly installed system the driver should install OK this way.

Run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

reboot

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

reboot.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, just to be sure I've understood you correctly, what would this reinstall?

Comment: I suggested to re-install the whole system to avoid various troubles caused by your possible previous wrong actions. But you can try without re-installing. These commands will update kernel and install new drivers that support your adapter.